# Moving websites from dedicated server to cloud server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, cloud, cloud-hosting

We have few website hosted on a dedicated server and in case we decide to move website from dedicated server to cloud server then what should we consider from programing point of view. All our website are Asp.Net based & use different session variable and rely on MS SQL Server standard 2012 database.

there is lot of information available on internet some of which is confusing and even confusion is type of cloud environment. Service provided sale team always push to move for cloud But when we ask these question then there is no clear answer.

I faced one such issue with shared hosting few year back when one of the web websites kept loosing session variable for same request by same user after investigating i found that shared hosting was farm based shared hosting so same user session was served by different servers in the farm which result in session variable loss in case first request went to server 1 & second request went to server 2. This issue was resolved by adding machine key in web.config.

and i have no idea honestly how cloud servers work. I am worried about session variable loss which i can get around by using SQL based session state.

What are the other precision that one should take before signing up for cloud based web server, from configuration or programing point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever one migrates to a cloud based solution one of the important factors to keep in mind is "State management" . When in cloud you are looking at scaling out with multiple instances and so an in proc state management is ruled out as load balancer will distribute requests to different instances and a session variable stored in one instance will be not available to another. So out of proc options like Sql db based are the options. I have been extensively using Microsoft azure cloud. and the options to set up an out of proc session state in azure are

1. SQL azure database based session state [provider](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers).
2. Redis cache based session state ( redis cache is offered as a managed service) [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/)
3. azure table storage based session state  [provider](https://niallbest.com/using-windows-azure-tables-to-persist-session-data/)

   In general out of proc is way to go and you can decide on the implementation based on the technology and cloud stack that you are choosing.

Answer (score 1):

There are few points that you need to understand while working on cloud server.

1. If we are using a single server such as ECS by Alibaba cloud or any other cloud provider, then the set up would be same as that we have with physical server.
2. If we are using managed service such as RDS by Alibaba cloud, then network string (db url ) needs to taken care of.
3. If we are using multiple servers behind load balancer on cloud such as SLB on Alicloud cloud then session maintenance has to be taken care off. It is recommended to use centralized session manager such as Memcache. Otherwise we would need to tweak the loadbalancer configuration.

Most of my references are from Alicloud as I have worked on it so bear with me. You can also check their web hosting packages

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this same research.  I agree with @Aravind that an external repository is the safest/best way to go; however, the loadbalancer that Azure uses (ARR) has persistence enabled by default.  Check your cookies, you will see an ARRAffinity cookie.  This means a client will always go to the same instance as long as it can, thus allowing InProc session to be used to an extent.

Again, an external repo is best, but if you need to get up on azure quickly, or without much effort, it is possible.

Update: you can now turn ARR Affinity on and off in the settings of a web app
[image]